# Can’t access containers with Postgres and MySQL from Python container on ECS run task

Tags: postgresql, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I created cluster on ECS Fargate, registered containers for python app, Postgres and MySQL databases on ECR. Created task on ECS and run it!

When I view the logs I see that MySQL container was successfully launched and ready to accept connections, but in my Python container I see an error, that my credentials are invalid for Postgres container! And in Postgres container logs say: Error says, that host is invalid (but on my local machine everything were fine within Docker established infrastructure)

To be precise about Postgres container error: `Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified…`

But in my container configurations I specified `POSTGRES_PASSWORD: examp`

Any suggestions how to fix this? Or maybe where the mistake resides

Comment: did you assign the host variable to be name of containers of the databases?

Comment: @M-Raw exactly that what I did